# Find the points in which a map is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F: \mathbb{R^3} \mapsto \mathbb{R^2}, F: (x,y,z) \mapsto (x^2+y^2+z^2-1, ax+by+cz), a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Find the points in which the map $F$ is a submersion.

My idea was to compute the pushforward (Jacobian matrix, in local coordinates) of $F$ and check where it is surjective, that is, where the matrix has maximum rank.
$J(F) = \begin{pmatrix}
2x & 2y & 2z \\
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}$.

I'm not sure how to go on from here. Do I need to compute the determinants of the $2 \times 2$ minors and deduce conditions from there? I don't seem to be getting closer to the solution by doing that.

(The exercise has one extra point, which requires to find all the points where $F$ is not a submersion and their image, but I suppose that should be easy enough once the first part is complete).

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating things.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ The maximum rank there is rank $2$ and that is equivalent to the rows being linearly independent.